# Подключить тёмную тему

Tags: android

Как программно подключить тёмную тему, вместо светлой по умолчанию?

Comment: В `AndroidManifest`:

    <application
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name" 
       android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo">

Comment: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/Theme.Holo').

Comment: как минимум сделайте `android:targetSdkVersion="11"`

Comment: там надо не `@style/Theme.Holo`, а `@android:style/Theme.Holo`